# Searching for a value in a DataTable column returns empty when the value exists

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

My `DataTable` currently looks like this (name = `dtRecipient`):

[image]

Using the following *LINQ* statement, I am trying to find records who have a *RecipientId* value equal to e.g. "marcus":

```
var found = dtRecipients.AsEnumerable().Where(row => String.Equals(row.Field<string>("RecipientId"), "marcus"));
```

But no results are returned whereas, as you see in the picture, there is a record for "marcus". What gives?

Comment: No spaces or other invisible characters? `row.Field<string>("RecipientId").Trim()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter not that I know of. How can we free the values from those vicious invisible characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No spaces or other invisible characters?

You can remove leading and trailing spaces (or new-line/tab-characters) with `Trim`:

```
var found = dtRecipients.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(row => String.Equals((row.Field<string>("RecipientId") ?? "").Trim(), "marcus"));
```

If you want to remove all non-printable characters you can use [`Char.IsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iscontrol.aspx) to detect them:

```
var found = dtRecipients.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => String.Equals(
        new String(
           (row.Field<string>("RecipientId") ?? "").Trim()
            .Where(c => !char.IsControl(c))
            .ToArray()), 
         "marcus", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I've also used `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to show how to ignore the case.